# New Vaadin app when run says my app is using components which are part of a Vaadin subscription

Tags: vaadin, subscription, vaadin-flow

I downloaded a Java-based starter app for Vaadin 14.0.11 from the [*Start a new project with Vaadin*](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) page.

When I run my app, and use a browser to connect to `http://localhost:8080/` I get this message displayed as a pink overlay above my app content (the "Download" `H1` title):

> This application is using components which are part of a Vaadin subscription.
>
> Click here to get a trial or validate your subscription

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of message appearing as an overlay on my Vaadin web app.]

I am confused. I thought [Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow) is an open-source project available free-of-cost? I do not want a subscription at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

In your project POM, change this:

```
<artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
```

…to this, adding `-core`:

```
<artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
```

## Yes, open-source & free-of-cost

Yes, Vaadin is indeed an open-source project. Yes, you can build web apps free-of-cost.

- A panoply of high-quality widgets are bundled for you to use free-of-cost. This bundled collection of components may be all you need to build your web app. Browse [this catalog of bundled widgets](https://vaadin.com/components) where the items without the yellow "Commercial" label are free-of-cost.
- In addition, there are hundreds of add-ons available, many free-of-cost, listed on the [*Vaadin Directory*](https://vaadin.com/directory) site.
- Casting a wider net, you can likely adapt most any [*Web Components*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components) based widget from third parties to work within Vaadin, if you so desire. Many such widgets are available free-of-cost. For more info, see the [*Creating Components*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/creating-components/creating-components-overview.html) section of the Vaadin manual.

## Commercial products available, but not required

The [*Vaadin Ltd*](https://vaadin.com/company) company sells some additional products with special functionality, as well as selling consulting and training services. Those commercial products are clearly labeled in [the catalog](https://vaadin.com/components) mentioned above. For example, Vaadin comes bundled with free-of-cost widgets for single-line & multi-line text entry, while they sell commercially a rich text editor. This is called open core business model. With this business model Vaadin Ltd can sustain development and maintenance of the free open source offering. So it is win-win both for those who use free and commercial offering.

## To avoid the commercial products

You can very easily configure your new Vaadin project to avoid any possible use of the commercial widgets. As your only take-away from this page, just remember the word "core". Search your project’s POM for that word `core`. You will find a comment saying:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
…
```

➥ Simply change that value on the `artifactId` element from `vaadin` to `vaadin-core`.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
        <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
…
```

I suggest doing a Maven `clean` and `install`. When you run your project, you should **no longer see that pink message**.

If you ever wish to try the commercial widgets, change that element back, removing the `-core` part, and follow the terms of their licensing.